# Android. I have two tabs and only one responds to touch

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost

I have an APP and one activity contains two tabs in a TabHost control, it worked fine, but now only the second tab works. I see the content in both tabs but I can only scroll and select an item on the second one. If I try to scroll the first tab this one does not move but I see the scrollbar moving and actually the second tab is moving, so if I return to the second tab now is in a different position. If I try to select and ítem on the first tab nothing happens. Here's the layout and the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_tab_mesas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TabMesasActivity">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/tab_host">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrl_tab1"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrl_tab2"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

```
package xxxxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import java.util.List;

public class TabMesasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabHost tabHost;
    List<String> lstMesasSala;
    List<String> lstMesasTerraza;
    clsBBDD bd = new clsBBDD();
    RelativeLayout layoutSala;
    RelativeLayout layoutTerraza;
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_mesas);
    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
    //Botones Mesas
    layoutSala = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    layoutTerraza = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
    tabHost.setup();

    //Tab 1
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("SALON");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("SALON");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TERRAZA");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("TERRAZA");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(savedInstanceState.getInt("tabId"));

    lstMesasSala = bd.SelectMesasSalaDB();
    lstMesasTerraza = bd.SelectMesasTerrazaDB();

    clsSoporte.AñadirBotones(lstMesasSala, layoutSala, getWindow(), TabMesasActivity.this, TicketActivity.class);
    clsSoporte.AñadirBotones(lstMesasTerraza, layoutTerraza, getWindow(), TabMesasActivity.this, TicketActivity.class);
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    //Guardar tab id
    int intTabId = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    savedState.putInt("tabId", intTabId);

}

public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent i = new Intent(TabMesasActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
}
```

Any idea why is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer putting the ScrollView outside the FrameLayout.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrl_tab1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```